Wifi gets disconnect after 10-15 min and then dont get connected to any network
I have upgraded from windows11 to ubuntu lts latest version from official site. It is stand alone no dual boot.
The problem is that when I was connected to my college wifi it works for 10-15min and after that it got diaconnected and doesn't get connected to any wifi , the wifi still shows and update available network but don't get connected to any of them.I have to restart the laptop after that it got connected and as same it gets disconnect. This is so annoying
Pls help asap pls 

Welcome ASK. Pleaase append to your question the result of the following command: - journalctl --since "2024-12-01 00:20" --until "2024-12-01 00:30" and adjust the time just before the event and just after. Some details of the wifi hardware and driver would also be nice 'lspci -vmm'  and 'lsusb'
